# I have tried to write a function which finds the intersection of two arrays

Tags: c, arrays

and I just cant understand why it does not work well.
Here is my function:

```
int* IntersectionOfArrays(int* arr1, int size1, int* arr2, int size2, int* sizeRes) 
{
    int* res=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));  //res is the array of the resolution of intersection//
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    *sizeRes = 0;

    merge_sort(arr1,0, size1-1);  //sorting the arrays//
    merge_sort(arr2,0, size2-1);

    while (i < size1 && j < size2) 
    {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
            i++;
        else if (arr1[i] > arr2[j]) 
            j++;
        else 
        {   
        res[*sizeRes] = arr1[i]; //getting the same elements of the two arrays - the intersection values//
        i++;
        j++;
        (*sizeRes)++;
        res = (int*)realloc(res, 1*sizeof(int)); //allocating more memory as required - according to the size of res(intersection)//
        }   
    }

    if (*sizeRes==0)  //if the intersection is empty 
        return NULL;
    return res;
}
```

this function compiles, but does not work when I run it.

Comment: Describing a problem as "does not work" is not helpful. What does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Also, why do you call `realloc` just to keep `res` the same size?

Comment: You might want to read the manpage for `realloc()` again.

Answer (score -1):

1- You are re-allocating memory each time you find the same element, by doing that the newly created array will have junk items in it. To see this allocate some memory and look at the contents of the allocated memory

Here is the new code, all I changed was the memory allocation

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#define min(a, b)  (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b)) 

int* IntersectionOfArrays(int* arr1, int size1, int* arr2, int size2, int* sizeRes) 
{
    //allocating memory for the output array, it's at most the size of the smaller array
    int * res = (int*)malloc(min(size1,size2)*sizeof(int));

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    *sizeRes = 0;

    //merge_sort(arr1,0, size1-1);  //sorting the arrays//
    //merge_sort(arr2,0, size2-1);

    while (i < size1 && j < size2) 
    {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if (arr1[i] > arr2[j]) 
        {
            j++;
        }
        else 
        {   
            res[*sizeRes] = arr1[i]; //getting the same elements of the two arrays - the intersection values//
            i++;
            j++;
            (*sizeRes)++;
        }   
    }

    if (*sizeRes==0)  //if the intersection is empty 
        return NULL;

    return res;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int array1[]={1,2,2,2,3};
    int array2[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    int sizeRes = 0;

    int * output = IntersectionOfArrays( array1, 5, array2, 7, &sizeRes );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: according to the instructions I got - the expceting output in this case is {2,3}. The intersections must include also elements who appear more than once in both arrays.

Comment: I call to reallocate in order to add one cell of memory in the array every time sizeRes is increasing in 1

Comment: what's the problem with re-allocating memory each time I find the same element?why by doing that the newly created array will have junk items in it? How should I repair it?